# How to remove nodes from a ref in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ref, react-to-print

I'm using ref to save the reference to a component that later is printed using react-to-print.

This component contains multiple components as children but not all of them should be printed.

This is the code structure:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
...

const MainCompoment = () => {
   ...
   const componentRef = useRef();
   // next method is passed to the components somewhere
   const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
      content: () => componentRef.current
   });
   return (
      <div className="container main" ref={componentRef}>
         <ChildComponent />
         <AnotherChildComponent />
      </div>
   );
}
```

A console.log was added to log `componentRef`. Stored it as a global variable and accessing it `temp1.current` it returns the html:

```
<div class="container main">...</div>
```

Now, I want to delete some elements that are not needed to be printed. I see that they are available inside `temp1.current.childNodes` in console.

Is it a way to delete them in code?

Comment: Why not conditionally render things inside the child components?

Comment: @TJ all elements should be rendered on the page but not all of them should be present in the print. does it make sense?

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/

Comment: Use print stylesheets, not JavaScript, to do this. `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />`